# What does BUILD.plasma mean in bazel project?

Tags: c++, bazel

I can't build project [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) with bazel because it fails with the error message below:

> no such target '@plasma//:cpp/src/plasma/format/common.fbs': target 'cpp/src/plasma/format/common.fbs' not declared in package

And I notice that there is a BUILD.plasma in ./bazel directory but I don't know what this is used for. So there are two problems:

1. Why "no such target '@plasma'"?
2. What is BUILD.bazel used for?

I'm a newbie for bazel and C++ project and I would appreciate it if anyone can help explain this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to build?

Comment: @richliaw I have to build it if I want to read the source codes of the project, right? otherwise the IDE cannot successfully build the index of the code lines.